# Grouping together getopts style args in bash

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

I'd like to be able to store a bunch of args in bash that I want to use in a bunch of different curl commands. However, my attempts so far haven't worked in the case where the arguments have spaces in them.

I made a simple bash script to replicate the issue, `getopts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    b)
      echo "-b was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    c)
      echo "-c was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The end result I wanna get is being able to call this script in the following manner, and work as expected:

```
OPTS="-a foo -b bar -c baz"
./getopts.sh $OPTS -d foo
./getopts.sh $OPTS -e bar
```

I called this in a few different ways:

```
[julius@julius getopts]$ OPTS="-a foo -b bar -c baz"
[julius@julius getopts]$ ./getopts.sh $OPTS
-a was triggered, Parameter: foo
-b was triggered, Parameter: bar
-c was triggered, Parameter: baz
```

The first one works just as expected, however, things go south fast:

```
[julius@julius getopts]$ OPTS="-a foo -b bar -c \"aaa bbb\""
[julius@julius getopts]$ ./getopts.sh $OPTS
-a was triggered, Parameter: foo
-b was triggered, Parameter: bar
-c was triggered, Parameter: "aaa
```

I expected the `c` argument to be `aaa bbb`, however, I got `"aaa`
Escaping the space didn't help either:

```
[julius@julius getopts]$ OPTS="-a foo -b bar -c aaa\ bbb"
[julius@julius getopts]$ ./getopts.sh $OPTS
-a was triggered, Parameter: foo
-b was triggered, Parameter: bar
-c was triggered, Parameter: aaa\
```

Heredoc is the same:

```
[julius@julius getopts]$ read -d '' OPTS << EOF
> -a foo
> -b bar
> -c "aaa bbb"
> EOF
[julius@julius getopts]$ ./getopts.sh $OPTS
-a was triggered, Parameter: foo
-b was triggered, Parameter: bar
-c was triggered, Parameter: "aaa
```

Is there a way to specify a bunch of getopt options together in a variable for reuse in bash? Why don't the above work?

Comment: Of course that works, but I wanna be able to reuse the exact same arguments in other commands, like maybe `./getopts.sh $OPTS -d foo` and  `./getopts.sh $OPTS -e bar`

Comment: Sorry, missed that in your explanation. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain that part well enough, I'll edit the question and make it clearer, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: side note: avoid using variables with names in ALL CAPS. System variables have names like that; if you use lower-case names, you won't accidentally use a variable with a system-defined use.

Comment: @rici got it :)